# Is ES6 module loader part of standard?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to clarify this issue.

Some articles on the net says that ES6 module loader is part of the ES6 standard. But I cannot find proves in the ES6 draft. But if ES6 module loader isn't part of the standard, how it's supposed to conditionally/dynamically load dependencies?

Comment: @AwalGarg yes. I've read it. But it's strange. Does it mean that we cannot load modules dynamically?

Comment: @yttrium: It means that you have to use an implementation-dependent loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a short investigation I found an answer.

There is no ES6 module loader specification in final draft. It only describes how modules should be loaded.

But there is WHATWG ES module loader spec, which is far better than nothing and for me it fits to stick with.

Related links:
WHATWG loader specification: https://whatwg.github.io/loader/
Related GitHub discussion: https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/issues/378